# CSV to Multi level JSON structure

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following csv file (1.csv):

```
"STUB_1","current_week","previous_week","weekly_diff"
"Crude Oil",1184.951,1191.649,-6.698
```

Need to convert to the following json

```
json_body = [
    {
        "measurement":"Crude Oil",
        "fields":
            {
                "weekly_diff":-6.698,
                "current_week":1184.951,
                "previous_week":1191.649
                }
     }
]

df = pd.read_csv("1.csv")

df = df.rename(columns={'STUB_1': 'measurement'})

j = (df.groupby(['measurement'], as_index=True)
       .apply(lambda x: x[['current_week','previous_week', 'weekly_diff']].to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={0:'fields'})
       .to_json(orient='records'))

print j
```

---

output:

```
[
  {
    "measurement": "Crude Oil",
    "fields": 
    [  #extra bracket
      {
        "weekly_diff": -6.698,
        "current_week": 1184.951,
        "previous_week": 1191.649
      }
    ] # extra bracket
  }
]
```

which is almost what I need but with extra [ ].

can anyone help what I did wrong? thank you!

Comment: Why all that choreography with `pandas` for such a simple task? You get the 'extra bracket' because you define it as an index hence everything under that index falls as an element of a list when serialized.

Comment: Thank you. What's the proper structure I should define it as, if index is not a good way for it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `pandas` for this - you would have to do a lot of manual unraveling to turn your table data into a hierarchical structure so why not just skip the middle man and use the built-in `csv` and `json` modules to do the task for you, e.g.

```
import csv
import json

with open("1.csv", "rU") as f:  # open your CSV file for reading
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)  # DictReader for convenience
    data = [{"measurement": r.pop("STUB_1", None), "fields": r} for r in reader]  # convert!
    data_json = json.dumps(data, indent=4)  # finally, serialize the data to JSON
    print(data_json)
```

and you get:

```
[
    {
        "measurement": "Crude Oil",
        "fields": {
            "current_week": 1184.951, 
            "previous_week": 1191.649, 
            "weekly_diff": -6.698
        }
    }
]
```

However, keep in mind that if you have multiple entries with the same `STUB_1` value only the latest will be kept - otherwise you'd have to store your fields as a list which will bring you to your original problem with the data.

A quick note on how it does what it does - first we create a `csv.DictReader` - it's a convenience reader that will map each row's entry with the header fields. It also uses `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` to ensure automatic conversion to floats for all non-quoted fields in your CSV. Then, in the list comprehension, it essentially reads row by row from the reader and creates a new `dict` for each row - the `measurement` key contains the `STUB_1` entry (which gets immediately removed with `dict.pop()`) and `fields` contains the remaining entries in the row. Finally, the `json` module is used to serialize this list into a JSON that you want.

Also, keep in mind that JSON (and Python <3.5) doesn't guarantee the order of elements so your `measurement` entry might appear after the `fields` entry and same goes for the sub-entries of `fields`. Order shouldn't matter anyway (except for a few **very** specific cases) but if you want to control it you can use `collections.OrderedDict` to build your inner dictionaries in the order you prefer to look at once serialized to JSON.

Comment: Looks very nice. Very refreshing thinking! Never thought skipping pandas. Will test it out today and post feedback. Much thanks!!!

Comment: #Tested above code. Works nicely. I made a couple of modifications. 1.) I have some fields which have thousand separators and quotes. such as "1,428.897" so quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC does not work for these fields. 2.) I need to add a timstamp column. 

# Modified code

import csv, json

def conv(s):
    s = s.replace(',', '')
    try:
        s=float(s)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return s

Comment: with open("2.csv", "rU") as f: # open your CSV file for reading 
    reader = csv.DictReader(f ) # DictReader for convenience 

    for r in reader:
        for i in r: r[i] = conv(r[i])

    data = [{"time": 1499437800000, "measurement": r.pop("STUB_1", None), "fields": r}] # convert! 

    data_json = json.dumps(data, indent=4) # finally, serialize the data to JSON

    print data_json